# Scraping using python and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape data from the following website:

http://mozo.com.au/credit-cards/search#fetch/680

Using chrome's 'inspect element feature' I have been able to locate the element address I want as:

```
//*[@id="p-40"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()
```

I was hoping using this code, I would be able to get the text "9.99%"

```
import requests
page = requests.get('http://mozo.com.au/credit-cards/search#fetch/680')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)


tree.xpath('//*[@id="p-40"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()')
```

However, the output is an empty array. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The problem is that the content of the page get's dynamically loaded. You should inform yourself about the concepts of scraping dynamic webpages.

Comment: any resources you can suggest?

Comment: It's nothing so spectacular... just know that pages can have dynamic content loaded and it can get messy because of it. You'll need a scraper that can handle javascript. E.g. [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [tobifasc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633917/tobifasc) said, the page is loaded dynamically. Try selenium for example,

First install:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Then:

```
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
```

Now you can query:

```
# With your xpath there are 2 results...
results = tree.xpath('//*[@id="p-40"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()')   
results[1].strip()
'9.99%'
```